# How to reason formally about programs using non lexical lifetimes

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following rust program:

```
fn main()
{
    let mut x = 1;
    let mut r = &x;
    r;
    let y = 1;
    r = &y;
    x = 2;
    r;
}
```

It compiles without any errors and I agree with that behaviour.

The problem is that I am not able to reach the same conclusion when trying to reason about this formally:

1. The type of the variable `r` is `&'a i32` for some lifetime `'a`.
2. The type of `&x` is `&'b i32` for some lifetime `'b`.
3. The lifetime `'a` includes `x = 2;`.
4. From `let mut r = &x;` we know that `'b: 'a`.
5. Because of 3 and 4 we know that the lifetime `'b` includes `x = 2;`.
6. Because of 2 and 5 we are doing `x = 2;` while borrowing `x`, so the program should be invalid.

What is wrong with the formal reasoning above, and how would the correct reasoning be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The lifetime `'a` includes `x = 2;`.
>
> Because of 3 and 4 we know that the lifetime `'b` includes `x = 2;`.

They don't. `r` is reassigned to on line 7, this ends the entire thing as `r` is thereafter a completely new value independent from the old one -- and yes rustc *is* smart enough to work at that granularity, that's why if you remove the final `x;` it will warn that

> value assigned to `r` is never read

at line 7 (whereas you would not get that warning with Go for instance, the compiler doesn't work at that low a granularity).

Rustc can thus infer that the smallest necessary length for `'b` stops somewhere between the end of line 5 and the start of line 7.

Since `x` doesn't need to be updated before line 8, there is no conflict.

If you remove the assignment, however, `'b` now has to extend to the last last line of the enclosing function, triggering a  conflict.

Your reasoning seems to be that of lexical lifetimes, rather than NLL. You may want to go through the [RFC 2094](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md), it is *very* detailed. But in essence it works in terms of *liveness constraints* of *values*, and solving those constraints. In fact the RFC introduces liveness with an example which is a somewhat more complicated version of your situation:

```rust
let mut foo: T = ...;
let mut bar: T = ...;
let mut p: &'p T = &foo;
// `p` is live here: its value may be used on the next line.
if condition {
    // `p` is live here: its value will be used on the next line.
    print(*p);
    // `p` is DEAD here: its value will not be used.
    p = &bar;
    // `p` is live here: its value will be used later.
}
// `p` is live here: its value may be used on the next line.
print(*p);
// `p` is DEAD here: its value will not be used.
```

Also note this quote which very much applies to your misunderstanding:

> The key point is that `p` becomes **dead** (not live) in the span before it is reassigned. This is true even though the variable `p` will be used again, because the **value** that is in `p` will not be used.

So you really need to reason off of values, not variables. Using SSA in your head probably helps there.

Applying this to your version:

```rust
let mut x = 1;
let mut r = &x;
// `r` is live here: its value will be used on the next line
r;
// `r` is DEAD here: its value will never be used
let y = 1;
r = &y;
// `r` is live here: its value will be used later
x = 2;
r;
// `r` is DEAD here: the scope ends
```

Answer (score 2):

### Life before NLL

Before discussing about non-lexical lifetimes (NLL), let's first discuss the "ordinary" lifetimes. In older Rust before NLL is introduced, the code below won't compile because `r` is still in scope while `x` is mutated in row 3.

```
let mut x = 1;
let mut r = &x;
x = 2; // Compile error
```

To fix this, we need to explicitly make `r` out of scope before `x` is mutated:

```
let mut x = 1;
{
    let mut r = &x;
}
x = 2;
```

At this point you might think: If after the line of `x = 2`, `r` is not used anymore, the first snippet should be safe. Can the compiler be smarter so that we don't need to explicitly make `r` out of scope like we did in the second snippet?

The answer is yes, and that's when NLL comes in.

### Life after NLL

After NLL is introduced in Rust, our life becomes easier. The code below will compile:

```
let mut x = 1;
let mut r = &x;
x = 2; // Compiles under NLL
```

But remember, it will compile as long as `r` is not used after the mutation of `x`. For example, this won't compile even under NLL:

```
let mut x = 1;
let mut r = &x;
x = 2; // Compile error: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
r;     //                borrow later used here
```

Although the rules of NLL described in [RFC 2094](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md) are quite complex, they can be summarized roughly and approximately (in most cases) as:

> A program is valid as long as every owned value is not mutated between the assignment of a variable referring to it and the usage of that variable.

The code below is valid because `x` is mutated **before** the assignment of `r` and **before** the usage of `r`:

```
let mut x = 1;
x = 2;          // x is mutated
let mut r = &x; // r is assigned here
r;              // r is used here
```

The code below is valid because `x` is mutated **after** the assignment of `r` and **after** the usage of `r`:

```
let mut x = 1;
let mut r = &x; // r is assigned here
r;              // r is used here
x = 2;          // x is mutated
```

The code below is NOT valid because `x` is mutated **after** the assignment of `r` and **before** the usage of `r`:

```
let mut x = 1;
let mut r = &x; // r is assigned here
x = 2;          // x is mutated
r;              // r is used here      -> compile error
```

---

To your specific program, it's valid because when `x` is mutated (`x = 2`), there is no variable referring to `x` anymore—`r` is now referring to `y` because of the previous line (`r = &y`). Therefore, the rule is still adhered.

```
let mut x = 1;
let mut r = &x;
r;
let y = 1;

r = &y;

// This mutation of x is seemingly sandwiched between
// the assignment of r above and the usage of r below,
// but it's okay as r is now referring to y and not x
x = 2;

r;
```